# State of development of Json libraries for Scala

Tags: json, scala

**Play-json** seems to be the only "well-known" to use macros for generating **typeclasses**, which suggests that other important ones ( Json4s, Spray-Json) have not been improved since a long time.

In particular for Spray-Json, an open ticket of more than 3 years ago propose this improvement (https://github.com/spray/spray-json/issues/59) and while the feature is available in some of the community contrib, it has never been merged in the library.

Compile-time safety seems an obvious feature that any mature library who is still developed should have. What is the current state of development of the Scala libraries for handling Json?

Comment: [Circe](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe) provides generic type class instance derivation similar to what Play has (but more powerful than Play's, since it works with ADTs, etc.). [argonaut-shapeless](https://github.com/alexarchambault/argonaut-shapeless) is also really good, but I'm biased—I prefer Circe. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use macros for this, shapeless offers everything you need, e.g. https://github.com/fommil/spray-json-shapeless

Comment: I got that, it's more about that having the typesafe generation of typeclasses seems an obvious feature to have now, whatever approach you use

Answer (score 1):

there isn't a language lib for dealing with json. Play-json is the library used in the Play framework, so it has some 'advantage' over the other.

Stil, [Circe](http://circe.io) and [argonaut](https://github.com/argonaut-io/argonaut) are really nice as far as I've seen.

I remember to have seen another few, but without most of the features these 3 provide.